# Stubing record creation in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, rspec-rails

I've a builder class which is supposed to creating new record, let's say:

```
ObjectBuilder creates Object
```

`Object` it's a `ActiveRecord::Base` inherited class.

I'd like to test in `Rspec` if specific record is created.

But It's good enough to test only if specific record will be created, `without database call`. So How I can stub AR object to check this ?

Responding to potential answers I'm not able to integrate `NullDB` to my project and I won't to create custom method in `Object` which will be responsible for creating record, and would be easy to stub. I would like to rely on `ActiveRecord` interface.

Comment: I haven't tried anything specific. I rejected 2 mentioned approaches. It seems as a common need so I think that someone came across it already.

Comment: There is no common need because: 1. you don't use the builder pattern for object creation in rails 2. you just stub `create` on the model class.

Comment: Another thing: your example is so abstract that it will be really hard to give any advise. please update your question with valid example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to decide exactly what you're trying to test here. If you're testing whether ActiveRecord works then you're going down the wrong path. ActiveRecord is itself thoroughly tested and any further tests you add yourself within your application are somewhat redundant.

Have a look here for the ActiveRecord tests, how they work, what they cover, etc:
https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/test

What I think you probably mean to test is whether your object is capable of being saved when you call `@object.save` in your application. If this is the case, then you can easily test this without really saving the object simply by calling the `#valid?` method. If an object is not valid, ActiveRecord will not save it.

Something like this would suffice:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Object do
  before(:each) do
    object = Object.new(attr1: 'required')
  end

  it "is valid with required attributes" do        
    expect(object).to be_valid
  end

  it "is not valid without an attr1" do
    object.attr1 = nil
    expect(object).not_to be_valid
  end
end
```

You can more comprehensively test the validations by adding the `rspec-collection_matchers` gem to your project and doing something like this:

```
it "is not valid without an attr1" do
  object.attr1 = nil
  expect(object).to have(1).errors_on(:attr1)
end
```